# Confusion about Javascript mouse event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent

I wrote a callback function to record mouse event:

```
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var callback = function (e) {
    console.log(e.type);
}

body.addEventListener('mousedown', callback, false);
body.addEventListener('mouseup', callback, false);
body.addEventListener('mousemove', callback, false);
```

what confused me is, when I do a click, in addition to triggering the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events, it will trigger `mousemove` event too.

Watch the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/r6Gqn/1/

Why is it that I do not move the mouse, but trigger the `mousemove` event? How can I stop triggering the `mousemove` event?

Comment: Are you sure you are not moving the mouse? even just a wee little bit

Comment: ``mousemove`` is not triggering for me on click. I think you might have a *very* sensitive mouse.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better it happens for me too, and it happens even if my mouse is in the air (optical, so it cant be moving). It does not happen in Firefox, but it does happen in **Chrome**.

Comment: Yea... it is based on mouse sensitivity...

Comment: What browsers is everyone using? I am using Chrome and `mouseup` also fires `mousemove` (even mid-air)

Comment: @musefan does it also fire 2 `mousemove`s when you right click (in mid air)?

Comment: There is also a bug here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=180505

Comment: @Gray: Yep, two event for right click

Comment: @hh54188 Is my answer not what you are looking for?

Comment: @Gray:thank you, your answer is one solution, but I prefer the the solution of the duplicate question

Comment: @hh54188 if that is the case, you should flag your question as a duplicate or copy the answer from there and accept it. Otherwise, this question looks open. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a workaround using jQuery (easier for me, I am sure it can be adapted for plain js). It seems like no one believes this is happening, but it happens for me in Chrome as well. (I am holding the mouse in the air, it cannot possibly be moving.) There is an existing **[bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=180505)** for it for Chrome. I could not reproduce it in FireFox.

Anyway, here is the fix I came up with. There is a demo here: <kbd>[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p337/uyZay/)</kbd>

```
$('#box').bind('mousemove', moved);

function moved() {
    console.log('mousemove');
}

$('#box').mousedown(function (ev) {
    console.log("mousedown");
});

$('#box').mouseup(function () {
    $("#box").unbind("mousemove");
    console.log("mouseup");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#box").bind("mousemove", moved);        
    }, 1);
});
```

Basically, this modifies the `mouseup` event to unbind `mousemove`, wait a *very* short time, then rebind it.